# Access Data from Factory in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- defining the module

  ```
  var app = angular.module("sachin", ["ng-fusioncharts"]);
  //making a service
  app.service('team',function(){
      var self = {
          'runs_aus':0
      };
      return self;

  });
  ```
- making a factory

  ```
  app.factory('taskFactory',function($scope,team){
      $scope.myDataSource = {
      chart: {
          caption: "Runs by opposition",
          subCaption: "Runs against each Team",
          numberPrefix: "",
          theme: "ocean"
      },
      data:[{
          label: "Australia",
          value: self.runs_aus
      },
      {
          label: "Pakistan",
          value: "7300"
      },
      {
          label: "South Africa",
          value: "5900"
      },
      {
          label: "West Indies",
          value: "5200"
      },
      {
          label: "England",
          value: "3300"
      }]
      };
      return myDataSource;
  });
  ```
- injecting factory and service in controller

  ```
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,taskFactory,team){
  console.log(taskFactory.myDataSource);
  //can't access data over here
  }
  ```

  /*
- all I want is to access the myDataSource variable in my Controller
- How can I do that?
- Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

$scope is used to expose variables to view so you shouldn't use $scope in factory. To achieve what you want, you can follow following code sample:

```
var test = angular.module("test",[]);

test.service("team", function(){
  var self = {
        'runs_aus':0
    };
    return self;
});

test.factory('taskFactory',function(team){
    var myDataSource = {
    chart: {
        caption: "Runs by opposition",
        subCaption: "Runs against each Team",
        numberPrefix: "",
        theme: "ocean"
    },
    data:[{
        label: "Australia",
        value: team.runs_aus
    },
    {
        label: "Pakistan",
        value: "7300"
    },
    {
        label: "South Africa",
        value: "5900"
    },
    {
        label: "West Indies",
        value: "5200"
    },
    {
        label: "England",
        value: "3300"
    }]
    };
    return myDataSource;
});

test.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,taskFactory){
console.log(taskFactory);
//can't access data over here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope is the service that expose controller variables to the view, and should not to be used inside factory.

app.service function is instentiated once with the "new" keyword, and its API should be exposed by the "this" keyword. i.e. this.myValue = ..., this.myFunction = ...

In factoy it's a little different, the function get called everytime you inject the factory to other function, it should return an object containing the API. for example:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  return {
    apiVariable: variable,
    getVariable: function() { return this.apiVariable }
  }
});
```